# NSTimer or NSThread in iOs 4 background mode

Tags: iphone, ios4, udp, nstimer, nsthread

I have to keep a NSThread or NSTimer when my iPhone application goes into background mode. Is it possible ? I have enabled the background modes  in info.plist and opened readstream and writestream  as follows ...(I am using UDP)

> CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, kCFStreamNetworkServiceType,kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP);
>
> ```
> CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamNetworkServiceType, kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP);
> ```

But when my application goes to background and locked state, NSThread or NSTimer is not calling .  So please suggest me how to achieve background threading in iPhone background locked state ?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder this too.

I want to update my CLLocation (current location) object every five minutes. The only way that i know of is to do this with NSTimer.

What is your advice if this isn't possible?

Comment: The only way out seems to be startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `NSTimer` use `UILocalNotification` which can fire notifications both when the app is in the background and in the foreground.

Answer (score 1):

For some applications(audio, location, voip) Apple allows [background execution](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) on supported devices.

Support for some types of background execution must be declared in advance by the application that uses them. An application declares this support by including the `UIBackgroundModes` key in its `Info.plist` file. Its value is an array that contains one or more strings with the following values:

```
audio
location
voip
```