# Run NSTImer in Background

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to run a timer when an application goes in background on iphone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSTimer or NSThread in iOs 4 background mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042418/nstimer-or-nsthread-in-ios-4-background-mode)

Comment: Ankur: 4 out of 5 of your questions are basically the same thing. Please stop creating new questions for the same topic, otherwise you risk people becoming annoyed and simply ignoring you.