# Keep NSTimer Running on background

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I have this following code which runs for 1 minute everytime user clicks a specific button.

```
timer = [[NSTimer alloc]init];
        timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

My question is how to keep this running if the application is in background mode so the timer still keep working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSTimer or NSThread in iOs 4 background mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042418/nstimer-or-nsthread-in-ios-4-background-mode)

Answer (score 5):

```
//NSTimer run in background.

NSTimer *myTimer;  <br>  
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:nil];<br>
   myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];<br>
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:myTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not `alloc` & `init` your timer.

```
NSTimer *myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
```

You can also stop it wherever you want.

```
[myTimer invalidate];
```

Comment: Could you also explain why you shouldn't alloc and init your timer?

Comment: `+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds invocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation repeats:(BOOL)repeats` 

Creates and returns a new NSTimer object and schedules it on the current run loop in the default mode.